# Is it possible to generate calculated plots/data from an interactive Bokeh plot?

Tags: python-3.x, plot, bokeh, interactive

I have a plot where there are some fixed theoretical points and the experimental points are plotted using a combination of multi-select buttons. Is there a way I can generate data of the %error between the theoretical points and the experimental data?

An example of the plot is shown below:

[image: Example plot]

Comment: Could you provide a minimal and easily reproducible example of the problem? Without understanding your set up its hard to say - you could either pre calculate all required data, or use python or javascript callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

This code displays the percent error as text next to the theoretical point. You can also draw a line on the canvas from theoretical to experimental point and the difference data will be displayed in a tooltip. The first click (button release) initiates the "difference" line. The next click ends it. The tooltip remains always on the plot but you could easily tweak it so it disappears after the second click.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS
from bokeh.events import *

source = ColumnDataSource({'x': [], 'y': []})

p = figure(plot_width = 900)

x_data = np.arange(10)
source_expected = dict(x = x_data, y = np.random.random(10), color=['blue']*10)
source_measured = dict(x = x_data, y = np.random.random(10), color=['grey']*10)

line_expected = p.line('x', 'y', line_color = 'blue', source = source_expected)
circle_expected = p.circle('x', 'y', color = 'color', source = source_expected, size = 10)

line_measured = p.line('x', 'y', line_color = 'grey', source = source_measured)

# circle_measured = p.circle('x', 'y', color = 'color', fill_color = 'white', source = source_measured, size = 60)
circle_measured = p.circle('x', 'y', color = 'color', source = source_measured, size = 10)

source_error = {'x': [], 'y': [], 'error': [], 'percent': [], 'text': [], 'color': []}

i = 0
for expected, measured in zip(source_expected['y'], source_measured['y']):
    source_error['x'].append(x_data[i])
    source_error['y'].append(measured)

    error = expected - measured
    percent = (error/expected) * 100

    source_error['error'].append(error)
    source_error['percent'].append(percent)
    source_error['text'].append('+{}%'.format('%.2f' % percent) if percent > 0 else '{}%'.format('%.2f' % percent))
    source_error['color'].append('green' if expected == measured else 'red')

    i = i + 1

# text_measured = p.text('x', 'y', text = 'text', text_color = 'color', text_font_size = '9pt', x_offset = -25, y_offset = 6, source = source_error)    
text_measured = p.text('x', 'y', text = 'text', text_color = 'color', text_font_size = '9pt', x_offset = 10, y_offset = 5, source = source_error)


line = p.line('x', 'y', line_color = 'red', line_dash = 'dashed', source = source)

callback_tap = '''

if (typeof custom_tooltip == 'undefined') {
        custom_tooltip = document.createElement('div');
        custom_tooltip.setAttribute('id','tooltip_div');
        custom_tooltip.style = 'position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 9999; border:1px solid black; padding: 10px; background: white; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px'
        document.body.prepend(custom_tooltip);  
}        

if (true === Bokeh.drawing) {
    Bokeh.drawing = false
}
else {
    if (!Bokeh.drawing) {
        src.data = {'x':[], 'y':[]}        
        src.change.emit()
    }

    src.data['x'].push(cb_obj.x)
    src.data['y'].push(cb_obj.y)

    Bokeh.drawing = true
    Bokeh.sx_start = cb_obj.sx
    Bokeh.x_start = cb_obj.x
    Bokeh.sy_start = cb_obj.sy
    Bokeh.y_start = cb_obj.y  
}'''

callback_mousemove = '''
function print(...args) {
    for (i in args) {
        console.log(args[i])
    }
}

if (Bokeh.drawing) {  
    if (src.data['x'].length > 1) {
        src.data['x'].pop()
        src.data['y'].pop()   
    }

    src.data['x'].push(cb_obj.x)
    src.data['y'].push(cb_obj.y)
    src.change.emit()

    tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip_div')
    tooltip.style.left = cb_obj.sx + 30 + 'px'
    tooltip.style.top = cb_obj.sy + 10 + 'px'
    var error = Math.round((Bokeh.y_start - cb_obj.y) * 100) / 100
    var percent = Math.round(error * 100 / Bokeh.y_start) 
    tooltip.innerHTML = 'Distance X: ' + Math.round(Bokeh.sx_start - cb_obj.sx) + ' px' + ' (' + (Math.round((Bokeh.x_start - cb_obj.x) * 100) / 100) + ' units)' + 
                        '<br />' +
                        'Distance Y: ' + Math.round(Bokeh.sy_start - cb_obj.sy) + ' px' + ' (' + (Math.round((Bokeh.y_start - cb_obj.y) * 100) / 100) + ' units)' + 
                        '<br />' +
                        'Error: ' + error + ' units' + 
                        '<br />' +
                        '% Error: ' + percent + ' %'
}'''

p.js_on_event('tap', CustomJS(args = {'src': source, }, code = callback_tap))
p.js_on_event('mousemove', CustomJS(args = {'src': source, }, code = callback_mousemove))

show(p)
```

Result:

[image]

Swapping the commented lines with the lines next to them makes the error percent to be displayed in a big circle representing the theoretical point. It looks then like this:

[image]

This script was written for **Python v3.7.2** and **Bokeh v1.3.0**